# How do I square a column from an Excel file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exponent

I've read an Excel file into python using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

water_consumption = pd.read_csv('Self_Data.csv')
```

and I'm trying to square the columns using:

```
exponent = 2
water_consumption['x2'] = np.power(water_consumption['Consumption_(HCF)'], exponent)
water_consumption['y2'] = np.power(water_consumption['Water&Sewer_Charges'], exponent)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

I'm fairly new to python. Is there any way to easily fix this?

Comment: convert water_consumption['Consumption_(HCF)'] to int(water_consumption['Consumption_(HCF)']) or float(water_consumption['Consumption_(HCF)']) depending on the requirement.

Comment: this led me on the right track. thank you @bazinga012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never use apply-`lambda` for straightforward mathematical operations** it is orders of magnitude slower than using direct operations.
The problem that click004 is having is that columns are in `str` format.

They should be converted first to a numeric, typically with `.convert_dtypes()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html

Pandas is quite good at understanding the type of column, the fact that it has been detected as `str` means that probably some of the values are not directly numbers, but may have units or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `lambda function` like this:
But this works if the data type of the column is not object type.
for this check `type(water_consumption['x2'])`
you try it:

```
water_consumption['x2']=water_consumption['x2'].apply(lambda x:x**2)



>>> import pandas as pd
>>> water_consumption={"x2":[1,2,3,4],"y2":[5,6,7,8]}
>>> water_consumption=pd.DataFrame(water_consumption)
>>> water_consumption
   x2  y2
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
3   4   8
>>> water_consumption['x2']=water_consumption['x2'].apply(lambda x:x**2)
>>> water_consumption
   x2  y2
0   1   5
1   4   6
2   9   7
3  16   8
>>>
```